# Why we don't need to bind this in async custom validators in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

My question is why not use `.bind(this)` in custom async validators in Angular?
whilst, we have to use `bind` method for sync custom validators.

```
this.signupForm = new FormGroup({
  userData: new FormGroup({
    username: new FormControl(null, [
      Validators.required,
      this.forbiddenUserNames.bind(this),
    ]),
    email: new FormControl(
      null,
      [Validators.required, Validators.email],
      this.forbiddenEmailsAsync
    ),
  }),
```

Comment: you don't need to use `.bind(this)` for sync custom validators.

Comment: In my case(angular 10) if `.bind(this)` is omitted, it won't be worked and throw an error(undefined error).

Comment: please provide an example in order to help you to fix it